# c++ - base class as property

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class `Player` and i want to have a member `primaryWeapon` that can be set to any number of classes derived from class `Gun`. Just wondering how to go about doing this. I've tried setting it up like this but i'm not sure where to go from here.

```
class Player : public Character {
    public:
        Player();
        ~Player();

        Gun primaryWeapon;

        void update();
        void move(float horizontal, float vertical);
        void fire();
};
```

Comment: You need pointers or references for polymorphism. `Gun * primaryWeapon;` (Or, better yet, use a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr<Gun>` or `std::unique_ptr<Gun>`.)

Comment: Tried this out. When doing primaryWeapon = new DevPistol() however, it throws an error "No viable overloaded '='"

Comment: What is the type of `primaryWeapon` when you get this error? If it is, for example, `std::unique_ptr` then you'd need to do `primaryWeapon.reset(new DevPistol())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using polymorphic behavior in C++, you need to reference the polymorphic object via either a reference or a pointer. Your example is storing the `Gun` object by value and this will cause the object to be "sliced" down from any derived type to the base type.

Whether you use a reference, raw pointer, `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` depends on the overall design of your program, but one of these will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you want polymorphic behaviour you need `primaryWeapon` to be a reference, a pointer or a smart pointer. A reference would prevent your player from changing their `primaryWeapon` which seems a shame. So that leaves (smart) pointers. If your player owns their gun I'd recommend `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

class Gun {
 public:
  virtual ~Gun(){}
};

class Glock : public Gun {};

class Player {
 public:
  void setPrimaryWeapon(std::unique_ptr<Gun> weapon) {
    primaryWeapon = std::move(weapon);
  }
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Gun> primaryWeapon;    
};

int main() {
  Player player;
  player.setPrimaryWeapon(std::make_unique<Glock>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to Gun for primaryWeapon;

```
boost::shared_pt<Gun> shrdPrimaryWeapon;
```

Then you define polymorphic function in Gun (like getWeaponAmmoForExample) and use it with:

```
shrdPrimaryWeapon->getWeaponAmmoForExample();
```